# Force browser cache invalidation on S3

Tags: caching, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, browser-cache

I'm having a frightful time stopping browsers caching my `index.html` on S3. I've followed every single guide I can find, and it just hangs onto it no matter what I do.

Earlier, I just used an `index.php` that then pointed to an `index.html`, and that worked perfectly. Obviously on S3 we can't do that.

So, now every time I fix a bug or make any code changes, none of my users receive them and it's obviously not a good solution to ask everyone to clear their cache.

Is there any working method of preventing this? I can't believe how aggressively everything's being cached.

There's:

- No service workers or anything
- All of this stuff in my `<head>`:

  ```
  <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
  <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
  <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
  <meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
  <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
  ```
- Invalidated the files on CloudFront
- Howled at the moon

Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Comment: is the index.html itself which is not being updated or the JS files you load within the index file?